# Multiple Custom Post Type loop logic

Tags: posts, customization, taxonomy

In short this is what I want to archive:

```
[template body] 
- default post title
- default post body 

[custom loop | tabs]
- tab 1 
-- tab 1 title 
-- tab 1 content
--- related articles to tab 1 by custom taxonomy

- tab 2 
-- tab 2 title 
-- tab 2 content
--- related articles to tab 2 by custom taxonomy
```

What I have is: 
- custom taxonomy 
- custom post type to list tab1 / tab2 etc 
- custom post type to list tab1 / tab3 etc content

The reason I am not using extended custom taxonomies is that I have to run translation and at the moment that is taken care of by using the old qtranslate plugin - which basically  has two instances of post titles, post content.

If I use extended custom taxonomies, I will not be able to use the translation. This is my source code: 
[Source Code](http://pastebin.com/Q3Jcu8QQ)

And this is my current output which is completely wrong:

```
[template body] 
- default post title
- default post body 

[custom loop | tabs]
- tab 1 
-- tab 1 title 
-- tab 1 content
--- shows tab1 related content

- tab 2 
-- tab 2 title 
-- tab 2 content
--- shows tab1 and tab2 related content

- tab 3 
-- tab 3 title 
-- tab 3 content
--- shows tab1, tab2 and tab3 related content
```

Well, I have left a debug in place and here is a test link - see the enclosed output in the red border :-(

Link: http://bit.ly/1ZnDVJa

Comment: you forget to initialise $slugs, with e.g. `$slugs = [];`

Comment: yes and not clearing it is probably why you are getting the repeat content, you are getting slugs for tab1, then *adding* onto those slugs for tab2 and then same for tab3.